# When does the Github free students pack benefit begin?

Tags: github

When does the Github Student pack benefits begin for services like Domain Name and Hosting? Do they begin when I get access to the pack, and last for one year for that date, or do they begin the day I start *using* those services while still under one year benefit?

For example, if I get access to students pack on 1st March, but I start using a free domain from 1st September, along with hosting, will the domain name and hosting expire on 1st March or 1st September next year?

Comment: I can't find an authoritative source for this, but almost certainly the latter -- the period of validity starts when you redeem the offer from the third-party service, not when you start the student pack.